# Regex replace - Ignore content in links

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-4.0

I have simple string replace which look for specific word and replace with something else.
i.e. if i have a key - bla and value - boo, below will produce

```
 var input ="bla bla test test1 test3...";

 foreach (var obj in dictionary)
 {
    inputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, obj.Key, obj.Value); 
 }

var output = "boo boo test test1 test3...";
```

Now I have html coming as input where now input can be

*"bla bla test test1 test3. Go to www.something.com/bla/something"* which ends up as

*"boo boo test test1 test3. Go to www.something.com/boo/something"*

(this content displayed in a html viwer)

Here I want to skip the replacement in the url so it will just do the replacement for everything but not the url. Is it something that possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may match a substring that looks like a URL and keep that text, else perform a replacement.

The code will look like

```
inputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, $@"\b(https?://\S+|www\.\S+)|{Regex.Escape(obj.Key)}", m =>
                    m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : obj.Value);
```

Note I used a `Regex.Escape` to escape potential special chars in the `obj.Key` with `Regex.Escape(obj.Key)`.

The `\b(https?://\S+|www\.)` matches a whole word (as `\b` is a  word boundary) `http` or `https` and then `://` and 1+ non-whitespace characters or `www.` and 1+ non-whitespace chars. So, if the regex matches a URL, it will be put in `m.Groups[1]` and inside the match evaluator, the replacement will be the same URL text, else, the `obj.Value` will be used as replacement text.

There can be another problem with this approach though, namely, replacing the same text two or more times. Then, you'd need to create a regex with alternations based on your dictionary  keys, and then use the match evaluator to get the right value based on the key match.

So, I'd recommend something like

```
var dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dct.Add("bla", "boo");
dct.Add("bla test", "ZZZ");
var pat = $@"\b(https://\S+|www\.\S+)|(?:{string.Join("|",dct.Keys.Select(k => Regex.Escape(k)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Length))})";
// Console.WriteLine(pat); => \b(https://\S+|www\.\S+)|(?:bla\ test|bla)
var input ="bla bla test test1 test3. Go to www.something.com/bla/something";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pat, m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : dct[m.Value]); 
Console.Write(output);
// => boo ZZZ test1 test3. Go to www.something.com/bla/something
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/ytZ62S).